# jquery.form.js need form to refresh itself after submit

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery.form.js plugin and my form is working properly with the exception of the form not reloading after submit. The form needs to remain permanently on the page, but the values need to be updated after form submit.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#personform').ajaxForm();
    $('#personform').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    });
});
```

I have tried all of the options I could find on the plugin homepage but am still no closer to the desired results.

Any help would be much appreciated please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

according to the [options](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) you can use `clearForm`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#personform').ajaxForm({clearForm: true});
    $('#personform').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    });
});
```

this will clear the form when submitting was succesful

Answer (score 0):

you would need to return false, to avoid the forms default submission behaviour.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#personform').ajaxForm();
$('#personform').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    return false; // to avoid form submission
});
```

});

The form will not be automatically reloaded as you are doing an ajax submit and you would need to reload or clear it.